# UISearchBar, remove "arrow" on the right

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Hi everyone,

I can't find anything about this UI element on the Internet. Do you know how I could remove this "arrow" on the right of my `UISearchBar` ? ( I'm working programmatically, without any Storyboard ).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the searchResultsButton

```
searchBar.showsSearchResultsButton = NO;
```

Comment: Youhou ! Thanks JordanC, this "Search results Button" started to make me crazy :)